# c3.js timeseries bar chart zoom in

Tags: c3.js

I have a timeseries graph done using c3.js. When I zoom the graph the bars do not change the width and the x axis does not adopt accordingly. Is there anyway I can do that? I have tried making **axis.x.tick.fit = false**. The zoom in works perfectly then. But the groups of data in the graphs are getting overlapped. Any idea on what to do is welcome. Thankyou

Comment: This seems to be an issue: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1386